# Check if 2 columns in dataframe are null, if so then delete those columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe is as shown below:

```
col_a1, col_a2, col_a3, col_b1, col_b2, col_b3,col_c1, col_c2, col_c3 
878       def    ert     123     nan     nan     001     ert    yui
999       erf    qaz     345     nan     nan     765     jkl    dfg
```

Condition:

```
> if col_a2 and col_a3 is null or empty them drop col_a1,col_a2,col_a3
> if col_b2 and col_b3 is null or empty them drop col_b1,col_b2,col_b3
> if col_c2 and col_c3 is null or empty them drop col_c1,col_c2,col_c3
```

Final dataframe should be:

```
col_a1, col_a2, col_a3,col_c1, col_c2, col_c3 
878       def    ert     001     ert    yui
999       erf    qaz     765     jkl    dfg
```

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe along with the expected outcome; then it's easier to help.

Comment: Have added:) @Cleb

Comment: What does "null or empty" mean? Is there a difference between a completely nan column and an "empty" column?

Comment: @HenryEcker  Null means if the cell is hardcoded with 'null' and empty is when cell is ' '

Comment: Thanks, but it would be even better if it was an example one can just copy&paste. Try to set up an example where the threshold to help is as low as possible :)

Comment: @ChandanN: Could you check whether any of the three answers solves your issue and then accept one of them? If there are still gaps, please comment below the answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do believe your answer is [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Edit: (Thanks for the remark Jeremy Caney)

Example:
Let's create the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a1': ['def', 'erf'], 'col_a2': ['ert', 'qaz'], 'col_b2': [None, None]})

 col_a1 col_a2 col_b2
0    def    ert   None
1    erf    qaz   None
```

Now we can drop col_b2 by using dropna on axis 1 (columns) and setting the threshold to whichever you need (I set it to 2 for this example)

```
df.dropna(axis =1, thresh = 2)

 col_a1 col_a2
0    def    ert
1    erf    qaz
```

Comment: This seems to drop completely nan columns, but does not seem to address any of the conditional logic in the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a1': ['def', 'erf'], 'col_a2': ['ert', 'qaz'], 'col_b2': [None, None], 'col_b3': [np.nan, np.nan]})

  col_a1 col_a2 col_b2  col_b3
0    def    ert   None     NaN
1    erf    qaz   None     NaN
```

Now we can use `.isnull()`:

```
df.isnull()

   col_a1  col_a2  col_b2  col_b3
0   False   False    True    True
1   False   False    True    True
```

So, for the condition you mention, we can now check whether all values in the two columns evaluate to `True`

```
target_cols = ['col_b2', 'col_b3']

df[target_cols].isnull()

   col_b2  col_b3
0    True    True
1    True    True

df[target_cols].isnull().all()

col_b2    True
col_b3    True

df[target_cols].isnull().all().all()
True
```

So, we can simply do:

```
if df[target_cols].isnull().all().all():
    df = df.drop(target_cols, axis=1)
```

yielding

```
  col_a1 col_a2
0    def    ert
1    erf    qaz
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your column names seem to follow a logical pattern, a small loop might be the easiest. I'm giving an example for col_XY with X: a/b/c and Y: 1/2/3 but you can easily adapt to anything.

In summary, loop over the groups of X, check if the subcolumns are all NA and drop the whole group:

```
for cols in [['col_%s%s' % (i,j)
              for j in '123']
             for i in 'abc']:
    if df[cols[1:]].isna().all().all():
        df = df.dropna(cols, axis=1)
```

NB. The column groups look like this:

```
[['col_a1', 'col_a2', 'col_a3'],
 ['col_b1', 'col_b2', 'col_b3'],
 ['col_c1', 'col_c2', 'col_c3']]
```